# Trying to install program, keep getting problems

Tags: linux, centos, installation

I'm currently an intern that's out of their depths here, this is really my first time using Linux, and everything I know comes from basic level tutorials.
I was asked by my boss today to install a program, and I'm following this [tutorial on it](http://dti-tk.sourceforge.net/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Documentation.Install), but am stuck at the Path part of it.

**Solved**

Every time I try to do this:

```
~$ export DTITK_ROOT=${autofs/cluster/name/MyUsername/more/path/DTI-TK/dtitk-2.3.1-Linux-x86-64}/dtitk
```

Like it told me to.

I get:

```
bash: DTITK_ROOT=${autofs/cluster/name/MyUsername/more/path/DTI-TK/dtitk-2.3.1-Linux-x86-64}/dtitk: bad substitution
```

Thank you user Muon

Comment: This isn't a MATLAB related issue. Please tag your question with topics related to your issue.

Comment: Sorry, the code that I'm installing is matlab, I didn't know if that would change anything or not, my bad

Comment: The `${}` syntax can be used to substitute in a previously defined variable. Could you try with just entering the path without that: `$ export DTITK_ROOT=/path/to/dtitk`.

Comment: @DumbIntern The link you provided even gave an example of how to export `DTITK_ROOT`. Consider reading documentation next time.

Comment: @edwinksl, you're right

Comment: If the second problem is actually a new problem, consider posting a new question.

Comment: Sounds good, will do

Comment: My new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644387/how-does-path-work-in-this-tutorial if any of you know the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, the `${}` syntax can be used to substitute in the value of a previously defined variable, and you've enclosed an explicitly typed-out path within it, so bash is looking for a variable called `path/MyUsername/more/path/DTI-TK/dtitk-2.3.1-Linux-x86-64` and not finding it. It should work if you run the command without the substitution:

```
$ export DTITK_ROOT=/path/to/dtitk
```